# JSP/EL output current URL

Tags: java, jsp, el

I'm awful at Java.  I've tried looking for this but it is surprisingly hard to find an answer to despite how easy I'm sure it is.

My URL is:  https://www.example.com/path/to/file.jsp

I just need to print it.  That simple.  Something like:

```
 <a href="http://www.foo.com?TARGET=https://www.example.com/path/to/file.jsp">Go</a>
```

I've tried...

```
 (request.getRequestURL()).toString();
```

...but it gives http://www.example.com/path/to/file.jsp - i need HTTPS

I've tried...

```
<c:set var="req" value="${pageContext.request}" />
<c:set var="targetURL" value="${req.scheme}://${req.serverName}${req.contextPath}" />
```

...but it gives https://www.example.com/

What's in the address bar is and always will be correct.  I just need it to have the proper protocol and full path.

Comment: What platform - version included - are you using? The implementation of `HttpServletRequest` is up to the platform to implement, and if `request.getRequestURL()` was returning a URL with the wrong scheme, that sounds like a bug that either may be fixed in a newer version, or should be reported.

Comment: CQ5, but I don't know what version it's running on.  I saw on a forum that somebody was having this same problem and they did create a bug report, but they were told it's as intended.  Hard to believe but...?

Comment: I mean I could do getRequestURL, strip off http and replace it with request.scheme, but that seems a little ridiculous...

Comment: MISCONFIGURATION:  Please see this discussion about root cause of this problem.  http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t128651-httpservletrequest-getrequesturl-returns-http-for-https-requests.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `javax.servlet.http.HttpUtils.getRequestURL(request)`.

Comment: Result:  http:// www.example.com/path/to/file.jsp.  I need HTTPS.  But thank you.

Comment: I'm quite surprised. Whereas, as I said above, the implementation of `request.getRequestURL()` is up to the platofrm, the implementation of `HttpUtils` is in the servlet-api.jar and can be seen [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax.servlet/servlet-api/2.5/javax/servlet/http/HttpUtils.java#HttpUtils.getRequestURL%28javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest%29). It directly calls `request.getScheme()` which you indicated above was working and gave you 'https'. I'm sorry I can't be of more help, but I don't know what's going on.

Comment: Maybe, if `request.getScheme()` works for you, you can look at my link to the implementation of `HttpUtils` and reconstruct the URL yourself? Something like `${req.scheme}://${req.serverName}:${req.serverPort}${req.requestURI}`?

Comment: OK well at least this is confusing more than just me :)  I guess I'll just rip the URL apart and fix it.  Awful.

Comment: Maybe something like `${req.scheme}://${req.serverName}:${req.serverPort}${req.requestURI}`?

Comment: I had that too and it did the same as getRequestURL().  So, whatever version of Java it's running has a screwed up scheme???

Comment: Well, not the version of Java. The underlying web application platform (WebSphere, Tomcat, JBoss, Jetty, whatever). But... yeah, maybe. Everything else was correct except the scheme? Very puzzling.

Comment: I marked it as correct since it is apparently how you should do it, even though for me it didn't work because there's some gremlin in the server.